# How to use Windows and Ubuntu simultaneously?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, virtualization

I want to use Windows and Ubuntu. I want to be able to boot into both operating systems, but at the same time use a VM to use the other one. Is it possible to do so? What applications do I need and how do I set it up?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you are asking two separate questions. In this question answer site please ask one question at a time. Please search the site for already answered questions.

Comment: You have to choose what OS is the HOST OS (the one that boots when you turn on your machine, an what OS is the GUEST OS (the one you run in a VM). Both Ubuntu and Windows can be HOST or GUEST.. There are lot of different virtualization software, VirtualBox and Vmware are often used.

Comment: I want to have the ability to use both os as host or guest. but I don't want to setup a vm on each host with a separate installation, but use the same Ubuntu or windows installation as a vm and host

Comment: I know that KVM/QEMU can use a partition as the disk for a VM, so perhaps you could make this work.  I wouldn't want to try it on my only computer, though.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I will try it tomorrow

Comment: You most probably won't be able to use the same Windows installation on bare metal and in a VM. It will probably think you are using the same licence on two computers and stop working. That leaves you using Windows only as a host.